# vee validate 3.x setting all fields to touched on submit

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

How can I set the fields in my form that are wrapped in ValidationProvider to touched when submitting a form. My current code is as follows using the ValidationObserver with a ref of "observer" to wrap the form. This changes the fields object in the observer but does not reflect in my ValidationProvider as being touched as I only show error when touched and error exists and the touched part is not being triggered.

```js
onSubmit () {
  const observer = this.$refs.observer as any
     
  return observer.validate().then((valid: boolean) => {
    if (!valid) {
      for (const field in observer.fields) {
        observer.fields[field].touched = true
        observer.fields[field].untouched = false
      }
    }
    return valid
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you try replicating your issue in a codesandbox, so we can see more of your code?

Comment: I don't think you want to mess with touched/untouched.  Try changing your logic in the UI - check out the [different interaction modes](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/interaction-and-ux.html#interaction-modes) and perhaps the passed/failed flags?